# How to remove IIS 7 on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, uninstall, iis-7

How can I remove IIS 7 from my Windows 7 installation?

Answer (score 16):

In the Control Panel, go to Programs and Features, then click the "Turn Windows Features on or off" on the left menu pane.  Then uncheck the IIS entries. (under "Internet Information Services")

Does that do it for you?

Comment: Does this uninstall it or just turn it off?  What if there is a sever misconfiguration that needs to be fixed - will turning it off and then back on actually do anything?

Comment: @cristopher - I did this. Nothing happens. On port 80, the same IIS awaits me.

Answer (score 11):

If you want a quicker way, Win + R to open a run box type optionalfeatures in the box and press enter,  uncheck the IIS entries, click OK then reboot.

Answer (score 1):

Control Panel >> Programs >> Click Turn on or off Windows features >> Select IIS components, that you wish to un-install and proceed to do so.

If you have any web instance/virtual directory - pointing to a UNC path, you might have to change that to a local path, for IIS to un-install (MS acknowledged a bug with such scenarios) [see link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/954856)